# How would I convert an object with JSON schema A to JSON schema B?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, comparison, schema

I'm pulling the same data from two separate databases to do a comparison using js. One database has JSON schema A and one database has JSON schema B. I'm required to transform the data pulled from JSON schema B and convert it to the same schema as JSON schema A in order to do a comparison.

Can anyone provide me with suggestions on how to accomplish such task? The data comes in as an object from schema B and i'm unsure how to take that object and transform it to have the same schema as JSON schema A.

So far I have defined the JSON schemas from each database and created two schema files. I'm wondering if there is a way to transform the schema with a particular library or something that can take the data and transform it based on the defined schema file?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for an outline of what you should or shouldn't include in your questions. Please try to provide examples of the schemas used as well what you have tried and any code you have that is not working.

Comment: Are you specfically asking about [tag:jsonschema]? If so, please tag the question as such. I don't think that [tag:validation] applies here? That said, I don't think there's an automated way to magically convert between documents of two distinct jsonschema files; you have to manually convert the JSON objects: using loops and assignments. Note that it would help tremendously, if you could [edit] your question to include a [mre].